# Firefox downloads run infinitely and cannot be cancelled either

Tags: windows-10, firefox

Of late, I've seen that whenever I try to download something, it hangs at around 99% and never goes beyond that value. Something like this:
[image]

If I try to click on the "x" icon, nothing happens. The same thing works fine in Chrome.

I've no add-ons added on the browser. Version currently is 70.0 and a new version is being downloaded but I doubt that will solve the problem as it has been going on for some time now (3-4 months)

Any idea what might be causing this? Does FF have some logs that I can look into and make sense of what's causing the problem?

Comment: Do you have any anti-virus running? Sometimes files are scanned after download which can look like the file has stalled

Comment: Nothing third-party. Out of box defender is the only one

Comment: Try using a fresh Firefox user profile.